# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for localhost when running Docker

Tags: apache, docker

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# CentOs base image
FROM centos:centos6.8

# install python, pip, apache and other packages
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python27; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-devel.x86_64; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-pip; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install gcc; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-devel mod_ssl; yum clean all

# Make a non root user so I can run mod_wsgi without root
# USER adm

# install Python modules needed by the Python app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy files required for the app to run
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 80

# run the application
# CMD ["mod_wsgi", "start-server run_apache_server.wsgi"]
# CMD ["cat", "/etc/passwd"]
# CMD ["cat", "/etc/group"]
# CMD ["find", "/"]
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/mod_wsgi-express start-server run_apache_server.wsgi --user adm --group apache"]
```

I can run the app:

```
$ docker run -d -P --name myapp jacobirr/pleromatest
```

And see tcp port 80:

```
$ docker port myapp
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Restless==0.13.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16
Jinja2==2.7
MarkupSafe==0.18
SQLAlchemy==0.8.2
Werkzeug==0.9.2
gunicorn==17.5
itsdangerous==0.22
mimerender==0.5.4
python-dateutil==2.1
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
requests==1.2.3
six==1.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
setuptools==5.4.2
mod_wsgi==4.5.15
```

Why can't I get to `localhost:32769` in the browser? I suspect this is related to:

•the user/group running apache?

•the fact that I'm installing `mod_wsgi` but it's nowhere on the docker "filesystem" so I have to use `mod_wsgi-express`?

**Update:**

'1' Netstat shows:

```
[root@9003b0d64916 app]# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 *:irdmi                     *:*                         LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     113181 /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/wsgi.1.0.1.sock
```

'2' httpd seems to be running in my container:

```
[root@9003b0d64916 mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0]# ps aux | grep httpd
root         1  0.0  0.2  64060  5084 ?        Ss   21:17   0:00 httpd (mod_wsgi-express) -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf -k start -DFOREGROUND
adm          6  0.0  0.6 350928 13936 ?        Sl   21:17   0:00 (wsgi:localhost:8000:0)  -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf -k start -DFOREGROUND
adm          7  0.0  0.1  64192  3248 ?        S    21:17   0:00 httpd (mod_wsgi-express) -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: EMPTRY_RESPONSE means that the TCP connection into the docker container seemed to be sucessful, however the server side closed the connection without sending anything back. Maybe check the `httpd` application logs inside of the docker host to see what happened, and if the connection attempt made it here?

Comment: `var/log/httpd` is empty and I've looked all inside my container for logs and don't see any there. In grepping around for httpd, I noticed this file: `./tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf` which seems to imply that port 8000 is in use... Not sure if that's part of the problem.

Comment: If you run `netstat -l` on the docker image, is port 80 open? Is httpd running and bound?

Comment: Updating question now with some new info.

Comment: @Robert that suggestion of adding `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/` made the traceback in the error log stop. `netstat` shows: `tcp        0      0 *:irdmi   ` and `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     113181 /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/wsgi.1.0.1.sock` and I see the same three `httpd` procs running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all your outputs, your httpd / uwsgi process is definitely bound to 8000, and this is the port you need to expose on the container.

This line in netstat, is showing a bind on 8000, and nothing else.

```
tcp        0      0 *:irdmi                     *:*                         LISTEN
```

It is not obvious here, but if you use the `--numeric-ports` argument, it will not convert the 8000 into its [known port](https://whatportis.com/8000).

In your docker file, again you should

```
EXPOSE 8000
```

When launching your container, you can also specify the port to use on the host machine:

```
docker run -p 8080:8000 --name ...
```

After this, you should be able to use your browser to hit

```
localhost:8080  ->  container:8000
```

Comment: now it all makes sense. works great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Dockerfile, just before CMD:

```
WORKDIR  /usr/src/app/
```

Assuming that your start-apache-server file is in that directory. This will help wsgi to find the needed file.